# My javascript validation just stopped working and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been developing this page for a few days for a school project and it has been working perfectly up until about 10 minutes ago. I didn't change anything except adding an extra javascript validation. Now when I run my page and click "register" button, it registers with empty fields instead of popping up the appropriate alerts. Please help!

```
<?php

    //Connect to database

include("dbconnect.php");


    // SQL insertion if submit button is pressed

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

    $firstname  = $_POST["firstname"];
    $lastname   = $_POST["lastname"];
    $email      = $_POST["email"];
    $username   = $_POST["username"];
    $password1  = $_POST["password1"];
    $class1     = $_POST["class1"];
    $address    = $_POST["address"];
    $creditcard = $_POST["creditcard"];
    $expiry     = $_POST["expiry"];
    $cvv        = $_POST["cvv"];

    $postcode   = $_POST["postcode"];
    $city       = $_POST["city"];
    $state      = $_POST["state"];
    $street     = $_POST["street"];

    $personcon  = $conn;
    $bbsSQL     = "INSERT INTO TBLUSERS (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, USERNAME, PASSWORD, CLASS, ADDRESS, CREDITCARD, EXPIRY, CVV, POSTCODE, CITY, STATE, STREET) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$username', '$password1', '$class1', '$address', '$creditcard', '$expiry', '$cvv', '$postcode', '$city', '$state', '$street')";
    $personinfo = oci_parse($personcon, $bbsSQL);
    oci_execute($personinfo);
    oci_free_statement($personinfo);
    oci_close($personcon);


    //Send Email

    $to      = $email;
    $subject = 'Registration Confirmation';
    $message = 'Welcome, ' . $firstname . ' ' . $lastname . '.' . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . 'Username: ' . $username . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . 'Password: ' . $password1 . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . 'Class: ' . $class1 . "\r\n" . "\r\n";
    $headers = 'From: fake@fake.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


    //Pass the message to the login page after registration

    $Message = urlencode("Thank you for your registration!");
    header("Location:index.php?Message=" . $Message);

}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>User Registration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">

function validate()
{
    //First Name
    var fname = document.myForm.firstname.value;
    var Vfname = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if(!Vfname.test(fname)){
        alert("Your last name can only contain letters.");
        return false;
    } else {
/*      alert("Valid first name!"); */
        }


    //Last Name
    var Lname = document.myForm.lastname.value;
    var VLname = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if(!VLname.test(Lname)){
        alert("Your last name can only contain letters.");
        return false;
    } else {
/*      alert("Valid last name!"); */
        }


    //Class
    var cl = document.myForm.class1.value;
    var Vcl = /^[a-zA-Z]{4}+[0-9]{3}+$/;
    if (!Vcl.test(cl)){
        alert("Your class must be 4 letters followed by 3 numbers.");
        return false;       
    } else {
/*      alert("Valid class!");   */
    }


    //Credit Card
    var cc = document.myForm.creditcard.value;
    var Vcc = /^[0-9]{10}+$/;
    if (!Vcc.test(cc)) {
        alert("Credit card number must be 10 digits.");
        return false;           
    } else {
/*      alert("Valid Credit Card!");     */     
    }

    //Post Code
    var pc = document.myForm.postcode.value;
    var Vpc = /^[0-9]{4}+$/;
    if (!Vpc.test(pc)) {
        alert("Post code must be 4 numbers.");
        return false;           
    } else {
/*      alert("Valid Post Code!");   */     
    }       


    //Password Confirmation
    var pwd1 = document.myForm.password1.value;
    var pwd2 = document.myForm.password2.value;
    if(pwd1!=pwd2 || pwd1=="" || pwd2==""){
        alert("Password unmatched!");
        return false;
    }
    else
        alert("Password matched!");
}
}

</script>

</head>



<body>

    <div class="author">
    COMP344 Assignment 1 2015 <br>
    Daniel Buskariol <br>
    42446937
    </div>

    <div id="heading"> New Star Public School </div>
    <br>

    <form name="myForm" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <table style="width:40%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" align="center">

  <tr>
    <th colspan="4">Enter Registration Details</th>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstname" tabindex="1" /></td>
    <td>Post Code</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="postcode" tabindex="9" /></td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lastname" tabindex="2" /></td>
    <td>Credit Card</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="creditcard" tabindex="10" /></td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" tabindex="3" /></td>
    <td>Expiry</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="expiry" tabindex="11" placeholder="MM/YY" /></td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Class</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="class1" tabindex="4" /></td>
    <td>CVV</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cvv" tabindex="12" /></td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Street Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="address" tabindex="5" /></td>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" tabindex="13" /></td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Street Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="street" tabindex="6" /></td>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password1" tabindex="14" /></td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Suburb/City</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="city" tabindex="7" /></td>
    <td>Confirm</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password2" tabindex="15" /></td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>State</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="state" tabindex="8" /></td>    
    <td align="right"><input type="reset" name="Reset"/> </td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Register"/></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
    <br>

    <p> Already a member? Click <a href="index.php">here</a> to login. </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: FYI, last names can contain more than just letters.

Comment: Open up the Developer console and look for errors. You have a typo. There is an extra }

Comment: Thanks for the last name catch, when I look in the console all I can see is SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: nothing to repeat (anonymous function) registerUser.php:56

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z]{4}+[0-9]{3}+$/` is not valid and the other one is also invalid. the + quantifier is not combinable with {n} quantifier.

Comment: @epascarello 
In the console I can see ReferenceError: Can't find variable: validate onSubmit registerUser.php:115 which points to my form but it hasn't changed –

Comment: I changed last name to [^a-zA-Z0-9\-] @epascarello

Comment: @bandoy123 - I've reverted your change, and restored the code to your question. Please don't delete the code, especially after people have been kind enough to provide answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up your developer console and it will point you to the error.

You have an extra `{` because you missed a `{` after the else. So either add a `{` or remove the extra `}`.

The regular expression is wrong because you have a `+` after the `{3}` and after the {4}. Get rid of them.

Comment: In the console I can see ReferenceError: Can't find variable: validate onSubmit registerUser.php:115 which points to my form but it hasn't changed

Answer (score 0):

In a few places, you put a `+` quantifier in a regex after already providing an explicit count, e.g. `var Vcl = /^[a-zA-Z]{4}+[0-9]{3}+$/;` (`{4}+` and `{3}+`). That's not legal in a regular expression. If you checked your browser console, you'd probably see a `SyntaxError` when the validation is performed.

Comment: How should the expression syntax for that be?

Comment: If you're looking for exactly four characters, just use `{4}`, not `{4}+`. If you're looking for four or more, I believe you'd use `{4,}`.